# htaccess redirect with special ? character for php string mod_rewrite in apache

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect URL's with a keyword string used in our AdWords campaign back to my home page using an htaccess rewrite rule. This is what I have already tried...

```
RewriteRule ^/?keyword=(.*)$ http://{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
```

example:
Looking to  make /?keyword=carrots redirect to my home page.

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle redirects involving **Query Strings**, you will need to use a

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`

in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/? [NC,L,R=301]
```